# GCC internal compiler error: Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, gcc, segmentation-fault, c-preprocessor

I try to include a file, I've defined in cmake.

```
-DUNINSTD_INC=$ENV{TARGET_FS}/usr/include/unistd.h
```

I checked this define and UNINSTD_INC is the correct filepath.

The code-snipped, which causes the segmentation fault is the following:

```
#define SURROUND(x) QUOTE(x)
#define QUOTE(x) #x

#include SURROUND(UNINSTD_INC)
```

If I compile the code, I get the following error:

unistd.h:1: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.

Does somebody have an idea to fix this problem?

Or an other way to include a predefined file?

gcc version: gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

Comment: Have you tried gcc 4.8? Also: what does the preprocessed source look like?

Comment: Inly can use this gcc version. Only this is in the OSS-Clearing.
In addition, I cannot view the preprocessed code, the segfault is at the beginning of preprocessing the code

Comment: Well you have to try to isolate the problem. does it work without the macros?

Comment: I found a solution without using this makros. Thanks.

Answer (score -5):

The fix is easy: Write a bug report, find out who to send it to, and wait for a compiler version that fixes it, as suggested by the error message.

Comment: Yes, this would be the easiest way. But I haven't the time to wait.

Comment: Your "solution" completely trivializes a serious question, and waiting for a compiler version that fixes the problem means stopping all work... again a useless suggestion.